# Unique Name must be specified for each listener when multiple communication listeners are used

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have created a .NET Core stateless Service Fabric application (v 3.0.467). I need to use both KestrelCommunicationListener and a ServiceProxy remote call for this service.

When I am deploying the application to the local cluster, it's throwing an exception:

> Unique Name must be specified for each listener when multiple communication listeners are used
>   [image: Service Fabric Explorer exception]

I have configured as below in the servicemanifest.xml file

```
<Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <!-- This endpoint is used by the communication listener to obtain the port on which to 
           listen. Please note that if your service is partitioned, this port is shared with 
           replicas of different partitions that are placed in your code. -->
      <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpointV2" />
      <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="httpServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="9098" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
```

and code sample:

```
  protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                 new ServiceInstanceListener((context) =>
                {

                    // return new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this);

                      return new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this,new Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.FabricTransport.Runtime.FabricTransportRemotingListenerSettings(){EndpointResourceName = "ServiceEndpointV2" });

                }),
                new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                    new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "httpServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                    {
                        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                        return new WebHostBuilder()
                                    .UseKestrel()
                                    .ConfigureServices(
                                        services => services
                                            .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                    .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                                    .UseUrls(url)
                                    .Build();
                    }))
         };
        }
```

Is there any mistake in this configuration?

Update:

Below code is the service sample method calling from the client:

```
 public Task<string> OnRouteMessageaAsync(string tenant)
   {
            return Task.FromResult(tenant);
   }
```

Client code:

```
 private async Task<string> RemoteServiceCall()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = ServiceProxy.Create<ICommunication>(new Uri("fabric:/AuthenticationServiceApp/AuthenticationServiceApi"), listenerName: "RemotingListener");
                var response = client.OnRouteMessageaAsync("tenant");
                return response.Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Sample code is in following GitHub link:
[serviceappcode](https://github.com/cvakarna/servicefabricsample/blob/master/AuthenticationServiceApi/AuthenticationServiceApi.cs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined multiple ServiceInstanceListeners. In order for Service Fabric to distinct them you need to name them using the optional `name` parameter of the constructor of `ServiceInstanceListener`. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.communication.runtime.serviceinstancelistener.-ctor?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Runtime.ServiceInstanceListener.%2523ctor);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet):

> **Name**
>
> Name of the communication listener. This parameter is optional if the Stateless Service has only one communication listener. If it is not given, the Name is set to DefaultName.

```
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener((context) =>
            {

                // return new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this);

                return new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this,new Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.FabricTransport.Runtime.FabricTransportRemotingListenerSettings(){EndpointResourceName = "ServiceEndpointV2" });

            }, name: "RemotingListener"),
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "httpServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                {
                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                    return new WebHostBuilder()
                        .UseKestrel()
                        .ConfigureServices(
                            services => services
                                .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                        .UseUrls(url)
                        .Build();
                }), name: "KestrelCommunicationListener")
        };
    }
```

Now, you have to use this name as well when you are calling the service using remoting:

```
var client = ServiceProxy.Create<ICommunication>(
    new Uri("fabric:/AuthenticationServiceApp/AuthenticationServiceApi"), 
    listenerName: "RemotingListener"); 
var result = client.OnRouteMessageaAsync("topic");
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply,now i am not getting exception ,but when i calling service using "ServiceProxy" i am not able get the call to this service method 

exampleCode:
  **var client = ServiceProxy.Create<ICommunication>(new Uri("fabric:/AuthenticationServiceApp/AuthenticationServiceApi"));
            var result = client.OnRouteMessageaAsync("topic");**

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, forgot to mention you need to use that name on the client side as well, see updated answer

Comment: Thank You, But even i am not able to call the method,Its not throwing any exception also,i have tried with wrong service uri which is not exists in service fabric cluster,
like **fabric:/Auth/AuthenticationServiceApi**even its not giving  an exception.

Comment: Ok, could you please update your question with the full code of the method that is calling the service using `ServiceProxy.Create<ICommunication>`?

Comment: So... if you set a breakpoint in the exception handler there is none? Now you are just swallowing any exceptions.

Comment: i have set a break point in service method,service method not calling  and in catch block too,but none

Comment: I have updated with the github link ,can you please check why its not calling?

Comment: On it. I cannot find the code calling the service in the GitHub repo, is that correct? What kind of application makes the call?

Comment: for testing purpose i am just calling from the console app, but i need to end up with the other stateless service fabric microservices  in the cluster.

Comment: Ok, and just to be sure, the application is deployed to your local development cluster, and your test console app is running on the same machine as the cluster? Can you post your test console app code as well?

Comment: Now its calling,But Dont know what is the problem till now ,but now its calling,Thank you very much Peter for your valuable time and response :)

Comment: Ok great, glad to be of assistance.